# como hacer para que el boton que esta en la derecha permanezca en su lugar en linea

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo clases desde la ic1 hasta el ic7 y cuando doy click para ocultar del ic3 al ic7 el boton que esta en la izquierda se apega hacia el ic1 y ic2 como hago para que se muestre en linea osea no se mueva de su lugar que se quedo estatico.

```
$(document).ready(function () { }); 
$(function() { 
  $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() { 
    $('.ic3').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    $('.ic4').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    $('.ic5').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    $('.ic6').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    $('.ic7').toggleClass('hidden'); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: No se que quiere decir inserta el código para poder ayudarte

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        });
        $(function() {
     $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() {
                            
           $('.ic3').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic4').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic5').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic6').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic7').toggleClass('hidden');
                           
     });
});

Comment: Para agregar código, lo puedes hacer desde la opción _editar_ que aparece bajo la pregunta. No lo agregues como un comentario.

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos el **HTML** con el que estás trabajando? También estaría bien saber que propiedades **CSS** tienes encapsuladas en la clase **hidden**.

Answer (score 0):

Declara la clase .hidden como:

```
.hidden {visibility: hidden;}
```

Esto ocultará los elementos sin destruir el modelo caja.

```html
<style>
  .hidden1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .hidden2 {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

<section>
  <h2>Botones sin clase hidden</h2>
  <button type="button">Botón 1</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 2</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 3</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 4</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 5</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 6</button>
  <button type="button">Botón 7</button>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Botones con clase hidden1 (display: none)</h2>
  <button class="" type="button">Botón 1</button>
  <button class="hidden1" type="button">Botón 2</button>
  <button class="hidden1" type="button">Botón 3</button>
  <button class="hidden1" type="button">Botón 4</button>
  <button class="hidden1" type="button">Botón 5</button>
  <button class="hidden1" type="button">Botón 6</button>
  <button class="" type="button">Botón 7</button>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Botones con clase hidden2 (visibility: hidden)</h2>
  <button class="" type="button">Botón 1</button>
  <button class="hidden2" type="button">Botón 2</button>
  <button class="hidden2" type="button">Botón 3</button>
  <button class="hidden2" type="button">Botón 4</button>
  <button class="hidden2" type="button">Botón 5</button>
  <button class="hidden2" type="button">Botón 6</button>
  <button class="" type="button">Botón 7</button>
</section>
```